# Why does VS Code auto-import intermittently fail?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When auto-completing in VS Code, it usually fails to auto-import.  Occasionally it works.  This happens for both local and `node_modules` imports.  (Happening in TypeScript files.)  It happens for all my projects including the simplest ones.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a speed issue.  When I quickly auto-complete, the auto-import does not work.  I have to wait until the autocomplete box is showing *and* the suggested auto-import is showing ~1/2 second later.

So the workaround is just to wait until the Auto-Import suggestion shows up, *then* autocomplete to get the import.

(That's a somewhat annoying slowdown when working at high speed since I won't always have in mind whether an item is already imported to a file... I don't know if there's an easy fix but there's a [GH issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106361).)